# Where can I find an AS1 reference?

Tags: flash, actionscript, reference, adobe, actionscript-1

I need to maintain some AS1 code, but I'm having trouble finding any language references. Does anyone know where I can find one similar to these for AS2 and AS3:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/class-summary.html

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=Part2_AS2_LangRef_1.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActionScript 2.0 was really just an enhancement to ActionScript. It added type-checking at compile time and a class-based syntax with new keywords such as `class` and `extends`, and the ability to specify access modifiers for variables and functions.

These constructs excepted, I believe the ActionScript 2.0 documentation should be applicable.